# Asking to shorten duration of 12 week internship

Tags: job-offer, internship, negotiation

I am very happy that I have an offer (haven't accepted yet) for a summer internship from a well regarded technology company. However, they are asking me to work 12 weeks, which is a bit too long for me because it leaves almost no time for break between semesters. What is the best way to ask them if they could shorten it to 10 weeks? My biggest worry is, would I seem uncommitted if I ask to shorten the duration?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason why you need 2 extra weeks off? I.e. family vacation thats already booked

Comment: Did you know that it was 12 weeks when you applied? Or did you ask if it wasn't in the job listing? In my experiences, companies tend to start and end internships around specific dates and have specific a specific duration that is planned well in advance.

Comment: This is a pretty bad idea. Likely, they will say no. This is more because 10 weeks isn't enough time to finish one of the projects, than it is about being mean. It takes a week for training, and then another week or two to get up to speed with things (at least). I definitely encourage you to go with the 12 weeks. 10 weeks would be potentially setting yourself up for failure.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the best way to ask them if they could shorten it to 10 weeks?

Be direct.

Just says something like "I'd really like to work here. But could you shorten the internship for 10 weeks, so that I can have some time for a break between semesters?"

Most employers would be fine with that. And you probably don't want to work for one that isn't okay with allowing you a bit of time off.

When you want something, you have to ask the people that can make it happen for you.

Answer (score -1):

This is your right to ask, and this is also their right to say refuse. Expect them to ask why, however. Saying "I want more summer break" is not an acceptable answer in the eyes of an employer, especially if the company has a lot of applicants. You have to walk a tight line, where you let them know you would *prefer* to finish two weeks earlier, but if this is not possible you will definitely comply with their preference.